# manipulating a data frame so that each person has all their relevant values in one row

Tags: r, postgresql, dataframe, dplyr, melt

I am trying to figure out the best way to consolidate my data frame and I seem to be hitting roadblock. How can I combine these two rows so that Michael's trial and purchase date sit on the same row?

```
         **user**    | **trial_date**  | **purchase_date**
         Michael     |   01-02-2016    |      NA 
         Michael     |      NA         |   02-15-2016
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `spread` and `gather` function from `tidyr` to get rid of the NAs, by first gathering the two columns into one column, then filtering the NAs in the combined data column, and then spreading them back out.

```
df %>%
  group_by(user) %>% 
  gather("type", "date", trial_date, purchase_date) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(date)) %>%
  spread(type, date)


#      user purchase_date trial_date
# *  <fctr>         <chr>      <chr>
# 1 Michael    02-15-2016 02-15-2016
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the first non NA values from each column after grouping the data frame by `user`, if all elements are NAs, `.[!is.na(.)]` returns NULL which is coerced to NA with `[1]` indexing:

```
df %>% group_by(user) %>% summarise_all(funs(.[!is.na(.)][1]))

# A tibble: 1 × 3
#     user trial_date purchase_date
#   <fctr>     <fctr>        <fctr>
#1 Michael 01-02-2016    02-15-2016
```